CSS Grid with possible content
I have a paragraph with some text, a possible span, and some :before and :after psueodo-content:
<p>Normal content without a span</p>
<p>Additional content with a <span>span</span></p>

I would like to pace the pseudo-content at the very beginning and end of the paragraph:
«   Normal content without a span               »
«   Additional content with a [span]            »

I though a simple grid with grid-template-columns would do it, but everything I try gets confused with the additional span element.
How can I get this effect? Should I be using flex instead?
Here is a sample snippet:


p {
  display: grid;
  width: 40em;
  grid-template-columns: 2rem ? ? 2rem;
  span {
    border: thin solid #ccc;
    padding: 0 0.25rem;
  }
  &:before {
    content: "«";
  }
  &:after {
    content: "»";
  }
}
<p>Normal content without a span</p>
<p>Additional content with a <span>span</span></p>




Flexbox and CSS grid aren't suitable here. Keep a default flow layout.


p {
  span {
    border: thin solid #ccc;
    padding: 0 0.25rem;
  }
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: "«";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5rem;
  }
  &:after {
    content: "»";
    /* you may not want the below */
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    /* */
  }
}
<p>Normal content without a span</p>
<p>Additional content with a <span>span</span></p>




I don't really see the need for the inline block, but imo this is the correct answer

@Symtox to be able to set width, you cannot do it for inline elements

I assume the reason why OP considers using only grid or flexbox might be due to this is only a minimal example. It could be an XY problem. Using inline-block or float here might not be ideal for layout purposes.

@HaoWu "a paragraph with some text" is never suitable for a grid for flexbox layout. The normal flow will do the job and I am not using float for layout purposes. I am using float to "float an element to the right" which is the purpose of float

Yes but I still think it is too specific for this example. However it is pointless to make assumptions here until OP clarifies their true intentions.

There are lots of things to consider thou, such as should the paragraph wrap, or when it wraps should the arrows align with the baseline or middle. Those could potentially affect which approach is suitable.

Idealy, if changing your HTML structure is an option, wrapping the whole content in another layer would be advised. This case your paragragh won't run into issues with arbitrary <span>s since they are in the same grid cell.


article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2rem auto 2rem;
  width: 40em;
  align-items: center;
  
  span {
    border: thin solid #ccc;
    padding: 0 0.25rem;
  }
  
  &:before {
    content: "«";
  }
  
  &:after {
    content: "»";
  }
}
<article><p>Normal content without a span</p></article>
<article><p>Additional content with a <span>span</span></p></article>




If changing the structure is not possible. I would use flexbox, however this may cause an issue when the paragragh is wrapped into another line.


p {
  display: flex;
  width: 40em;
  
  span {
    border: thin solid #ccc;
    padding: 0 0.25rem;
  }
  
  &:before {
    content: "«";
  }
  
  &:after {
    content: "»";
    margin-inline-start: auto;
  }
}
<p>Normal content without a span</p>
<p>Additional content with a <span>span</span></p>



You may also use grid together with display: contents, so the inner <span> is treated as a plain text. But that means you lose some styling options like borders or paddings etc. Also be aware of its coverage.


p {
  display: grid;
  width: 40em;
  grid-template-columns: 2rem auto 2rem;
  span {
    display: contents;
    color: red;
    border: thin solid #ccc;
    padding: 0 0.25rem;
  }
  &:before {
    content: "«";
  }
  &:after {
    content: "»";
  }
}
<p>Normal content without a span</p>
<p>Additional content with a <span>span</span></p>



